# How do I run SharePoint designer 2013 as a different user?

Tags: sharepoint-designer

How do I run SharePoint designer 2013 as a different user? In 2010 version there is a little button on the bottom to change user, but it is not here anymore. I also can try to do the shift+right click and run as different user, but when I do that on the shortcut, I don't get the option to run as a different user. I also can't find the install location of sharepoint designer 2013. According to this https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2738178 there should be a `Spedesign.exe` but I can't find it.

Does anyone know?

Thanks

Answer (score 13):

The SharePoint Designer 2013 executable is named "SPDESIGN.EXE".  If you have the 32-bit version it will be in c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office15\ otherwise it is in the location described in the MS document you linked to in your question.  Then Shift + Right-Click to "Run as a different user".

Answer (score 3):

**Try to do the following:**

- Right-click on Sharepoint Designer and select Run as a different user,
- If you can't find this option, Select open file location > Press `Shift + Righ-click` > Select Run as Diff user

[image]

> You can also check another method from this ref : [Sign in as Different User in SharePoint Designer 2013](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/open-sharepoint-designer-as-different-user/)

Answer (score 2):

As @Erik mentionned, you have to find the exe and "shift right-click" to get the Run as a different user.

If you plan to use it in the long run, you can also create yourself a shortcut with this target :

C:\WINDOWS\system32\runas.exe /user:domain\account "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office15\SPDesign.exe"

runas command line : https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771525.aspx

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of ways you can achieve this one of your option is

1- Depending on your installation go to

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office15
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office15

2 – Press and hold the Shift key, right-click Spedesign.exe, and then click Run as different user.

3 -Type the credential of the user and then click OK

You can also check this post for more info: [How to run SharePoint Designer 2013 or 2010 as different user](http://www.mytechnology.space/how-to-run-sharepoint-designer-2013-or-2010-as-different-user/)